# Setting multiple styles to a custom LabelItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I made a custom LabelItemRenderer, inside it I want to give some additional style to a StyleableTextField. How can I do it without losing inherited styles? I tried different things, but always got an error saying antiAliasType must be set.

```
s|List.customListStyle
{
    fontFamily: Arial;
    fontSize: 18;
    contentBackgroundAlpha: 0.25;
    verticalScrollPolicy: auto;
    downColor: #CCCCCC;
}
s|List.customListStyle sw|CustomListItemRenderer
{
    paddingLeft: 20;
}
```

How should I set my text field style, and then set it in the createChildren method?

Comment: If you extended a class, you should inherit all styles automatically.  What makes you think you're losing them? What line of code is giving the error?  Is this a code problem or a CSS problem?

Comment: The thing is I don't want all my LabelItemRenderer to get the styles of that inner StyleableTextField. I could use setStyle(), but would like to make it by using CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I wasn't able to achieve this by using an external CSS and didn't get any reply I decided to use setStyle. It's not what I wanted, but it works...